# Sequelize seeder doesn't find correct column name of model

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a model "Currency" which is a table with only one column (name), in a nodeJS project using sequelize as the ORM. I've created a seeder for it but when I run the seeder it doesn't find the correct name of the column. The model is:

`./app/models/Currency.js`:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Currency = sequelize.define('Currency', {
      name: { 
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      }
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'currency',
      timestamps: false,
      id: false
    }
    );
    Currency.removeAttribute('id')
    return Currency
  }
```

the seeder file, `./database/seeders/20190705045938-SeedCurrency.js`:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface) {
    return queryInterface.bulkUpdate('currency', [
        { name: 'USD' },
        { name: 'BRL' },
        { name: 'EUR' },
        { name: 'BTC' }
    ], {});
  },

  down: function(queryInterface) {
     return queryInterface.bulkDelete('currency', null, {});
  }
};
```

When I run `node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:seed:all` it fails with the error:

> == 20190705045938-SeedCurrency: migrating =======
>
> ERROR: column "0" of relation "currency" does not exist

What did I miss when configuring this relation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `bulkCreate` instead of `bulkUpdate`?

Comment: `ERROR: queryInterface.bulkCreate is not a function`

Comment: Pardon me, it's `bulkInsert`.

Comment: thanks, now it's working! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `queryInterface.bulkInsert` instead of `bulkUpdate`.